# i trying to add android platform in ionic but its not working , it showing errors

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to add android platform in ionic but its not working , it showing the following errors:

```
C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\first app\RoomBooking>cordova platform add android

Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~6.3.0
Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@~6.3.0
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 4294963248 Error output:
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\first app\RoomBooking\node_modules\.stagin
g
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\
first app\RoomBooking\node_modules\.staging'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Lenovo\Deskt
op\first app\RoomBooking\node_modules\.staging'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'C:\\Users\\Le
novo\\Desktop\\first app\\RoomBooking\\node_modules\\.staging\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\first app\\RoomBooking\\node_modul
es\\.staging' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-11-26T21_56_46
_792Z-debug.log
```

**what should i do?**

Comment: Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect. Check your connection and platform name/version/URL

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an issue with npm. Try downgrading npm, run the following command:

```
npm install -g npm@5.3
```